# Executing Sql script file in Groovy/Gradle

Tags: mysql, groovy, gradle

```
def db = [
    moduleGroup: 'mysql',
    moduleName: 'mysql-connector-java',
    moduleVersion: '5.1.18',
    driver: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bham',
    user: mySqlUser,
    password: mySqlPassword
]

configurations {
    sql
}    


task connect << {

        // This is needed to get mySql driver onto the Groovy/Gradle classpath 
        configurations.sql.each { file ->
          println "Adding URL: $file"
          gradle.class.classLoader.addURL(file.toURI().toURL())
        }

        def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)

        sql.execute("actStatusCodeLkp.sql") 
        String sqlFilePath = "src/main/resources/sqlscripts/actStatusCodeLkp.sql"
        String sqlString = new File(sqlFilePath).text
        sql.execute(sqlString)

        sql.close()

     }
```

**actStatusCodeLkp.sql**

```
insert into act_status_code (id, code, display_name, code_system_name, code_system) values (1, 'active', 'active', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14');
insert into act_status_code (id, code, display_name, code_system_name, code_system) values (2, 'cancelled', 'cancelled', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14');
insert into act_status_code (id, code, display_name, code_system_name, code_system) values (3, 'aborted', 'aborted', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14');
insert into act_status_code (id, code, display_name, code_system_name, code_system) values (4, 'completed', 'completed', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14');
```

It seems that sql.execute command does not tokenize the file into 4 different insert statements and throws.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
 server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into act_status_code (id, code, display_name, code_system_name, code_syst' at line 2
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
```

**It works if I just keep one insert statement in the file.** What is the clean work around here, did not really find anything regarding this online.
Also, when using maven, I am able to run the same sql file using sql-maven-plugin.

Comment: You can't execute multi-line statements with the Sql class.  You may have more success with something like this? http://blog.codeborne.com/2012/09/using-dbdeploy-in-gradle.html

Comment: You could also call readLines on the file, which gets you a list and then each() on that list and call sql.executeInsert with the line. That might help.

Comment: After doing some research I figured for MySql I need to specify `allowMultiQueries: 'true'`. It works like charm, but if I have any comments in my file such as `--insert into ..`, it fails with the same reason, I guess there should be a way to escape the commented lines?

Answer (score 8):

Something like this helped me.  Notice getting allowMultiQueries: 'true' in the properties

```
def props = [user: grailsApplication.config.dataSource.username, password: grailsApplication.config.dataSource.password, allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties
    def url = grailsApplication.config.dataSource.url
    def driver = grailsApplication.config.dataSource.driverClassName


    def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, props, driver)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also change your sql to make the statement one query by:

```
insert into act_status_code (id, code, display_name, code_system_name, code_system) values 
(1, 'active', 'active', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14'),
(2, 'cancelled', 'cancelled', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14'),
(3, 'aborted', 'aborted', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14'),
(4, 'completed', 'completed', 'ActStatus', '2.16.840.1.113883.5.14');
```